# Is there a list of field types for a Sencha Touch model?

Tags: model, types, field, sencha-touch

Is there a list of available field types for a Sencha Touch model?
I've searched the docu but couldn't find something like this.

You can use "inte", "string", "boolean", "timestamp" but what else? Is there a "time", a "date" oder a "datetime" and how do they behave?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: no, I don't find an answer :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's taken a good part of the afternoon, but I believe I've found the definitive list.

Model members in Ext created using the [Field](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field) class.

If you click on the [type](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type) config option, you'll be presented with the definitive list from source.

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but just for people that find this via Google, but the [Components](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/components) page in the Touch 2 guide gives the definitive list for Sencha Touch 2.

Comment: Don't think so, the list for Sencha Touch 2 is http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field

Answer (score 2):

Type Ext.data.Types into the web console.  This is what I got for Sencha Touch 2.1:

- AUTO: Object
- BOOL: Object
- BOOLEAN: Object
- DATE: Object
- FLOAT: Object
- INT: Object
- INTEGER: Object
- NUMBER: Object
- STRING: Object

Answer (score 1):

For model data field types, see the documentation for Ext.data.Types. Lists
auto, string, int, float, bool, date.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha needs to make this easier to find. I finally discovered it on the [Ext.Component page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Component). Unfortunately, the list there is incomplete. It's missing a bunch of types including `datepickerfield` and `emailfield`. Your best bet for a complete list is to search the source code for `Ext.reg(` (the first argument is the xtype).

Comment: You're referring to Component xtypes but the question was about data Model field types. Kim3er has the correct answer above